# OnNavigatedTo won't be triggered?

Tags: silverlight

I wanna do some check when a page was shown. The check code is written in OnNavigatedTo() function. However, I found if I navigated to a page by Hyperlink, OnNavigatedTo() would be executed, but if I write this code in a click event of a button, OnNavigatedTo() won't be execute.

```
this.Content = new SOMEPAGE();
```

Could you tell me how to make sure my check code run every time the page was shown? Any better navigation method can I use to instead of "this.Content" to make OnNavigatedTo() be executed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to navigate to another page could be launched in a click event:

```
            Frame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual.GetDescendant<Frame>();
        frame.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Err.. I don't wanna navigate the whole page to another one... I just need to navigate the page within a frame to another one...

Comment: I just gave an alternate method of frame navigation here.  For when you don't have the ContentFrame object, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the code behind of a page loaded in your Navigation Frame, you can use the NavigationService property found on the Page base class (which your page inherits from by default).

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If you are working in the code behind of your MainPage, you can access your navigation frame directly (defaultly named ContentFrame in your xaml).

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("SomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```