# Navigation between Silverlight pages with MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, user-controls, navigation

I am creating simple app on Silverlight 4.
In folder of View I have 2(Silverlight Pages) also in ViewModel I have 2 ViewModels.
In Silverligh project I have UserControl that hold one of page.
I need simple example of using navigation.
For example I click on button, call some method in ViewModel and this method redirect me on another Silverligh Page.Please help me, I'm suffering 3 day, and I found only very hard examples, but I bealive in simple.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WebServerApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:pagescol="clr-namespace:SilverlightServerLib.View;assembly=SilverlightServerLib"

    Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <pagescol:SettingsPage/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

That was a UserControll that hold first Page, I need navigate to another Page.
Thank You very much!

Comment: Does this help?  
[Navigation alternatives, works in a user control][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931669/onnavigatedto-wont-be-triggered/9932057#9932057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u should use a Frame control from Navigation framework(silverlight tookit).
then u can try such approach

```
<Button Content="Click">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <actions:NavigateAction UriPath="/Home" TargetName="MainFrame" />
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<navigation:Frame x:Name="MainFrame"                          
                  UriMapper="{StaticResource UriMapper}" />
```

and the appropriate code for the NavigateAction:

```
public class NavigateAction : TargetedTriggerAction<Frame>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UriPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UriPath", typeof(string), typeof(NavigateAction), null);

    public string UriPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriPathProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        Target.Navigate(new Uri(UriPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

Also, u should allways use an UriMapper. It is a nice practice:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sdk:UriMapper x:Key="UriMapper">
        <sdk:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/TasksView.xaml" Uri="" />
        <sdk:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/{view}View.xaml" Uri="/{view}" />
    </sdk:UriMapper>
</Application.Resources>
```